# I am trying to read a file using Buffered Reader. How can I gave the relative path of file?

Tags: java

I am trying to read a file using a buffered reader. How can I read the file giving a relative path?

When I am giving this path , it is working fine:

```
File file = new File("/home/workspace_ag7_tmv/Message Router/environments/wb/conf/subscriber_content_restriction.conf");
```

Now when I am trying to do like this :

```
File file = new File("AG_HOME/conf/subscriber_content_restriction.conf");

AG_HOME = "/home/workspace_ag7_tmv/Message Router/environments/wb/"
```

This `AG_HOME` path , defined in debug configuration of eclipse.

When I am running, getting `FilenotFould exception`.

Is there any way to do the same ?

```
File file = new File("AG_HOME/conf/subscriber_content_restriction.conf");

AG_HOME = /home/workspace_ag7_tmv/Message Router/environments/wb/"
```

Comment: AG_HOME = "/home/workspace_ag7_tmv/Message Router/environments/wb/";

typo

Answer (score 0):

In the code you've attached you use the name of the variable, not the value.

If *AG_HOME* is a system variable as well, you can get it's value from *System* (`System.getenv("AG_HOME")`). If it is declared in the scope of your runtime session by eclipse, explore Eclipse Runtime api to get access to it's variables.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to give relative path to file and donot care about path variables, then
`File file = new File("subscriber_content_restriction.conf");` should be sufficient where `subscriber_content_restriction.conf` will have to be in classpath during compilation. Or if you are using maven put it under `src/main/resources`.

If above style is mandatory, then maybe you should be doing

```
File file = new File(AG_HOME+"/conf/subscriber_content_restriction.conf");
```